# Minimum order amount except for specific shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In WooCommerce, I use the following code to set a minimum order amount:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {

    $minimum = 50; // Hier gibst du den Mindestbestellwert ein
    
    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) { 
        if( is_cart() ) { 
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 'Der Mindestbestellwert beträgt %s pro Bestellung. Der aktuelle Bestellwert beträgt %s.' , // Text fuer Warenkorb 
                wc_price( $minimum ), 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Der Mindestbestellwert beträgt %s pro Bestellung. Der aktuelle Bestellwert beträgt %s.' , // Text fuer Kasse
                wc_price( $minimum ),
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Now if the customer chooses "self pickup" ("Local pickup shipping method), I don't want any minimum required order amount.

How can I set Minimum order amount except for "Local pickup" shipping method in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 1):

Based on *[Getting minimum order amount for 'Free Shipping' method in checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201045/getting-minimum-order-amount-for-free-shipping-method-in-checkout-page/42201311#42201311)* answer code and also *[Set a minimum order amount in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038477/set-a-minimum-order-amount-in-woocommerce/55040834#55040834)* answer code, here is the correct way to set a Minimum order amount except for specific shipping method in WooCommerce:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_minimum_required_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_required_order_amount() {

    // HERE Your settings
    $minimum_amount     = 50; // The minimum cart total amount
    $shipping_method_id = 'local_pickup'; // The targeted shipping method Id (exception)

    // Get some variables
    $cart_total     = (float) WC()->cart->total; // Total cart amount
    $chosen_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // Chosen shipping method rate Ids (array)

    // Only when a shipping method has been chosen
    if ( ! empty($chosen_methods) ) {
        $chosen_method  = explode(':', reset($chosen_methods)); // Get the chosen shipping method Id (array)
        $chosen_method_id = reset($chosen_method); // Get the chosen shipping method Id
    }

    // If "Local pickup" shipping method is chosen, exit (no minimun is required)
    if ( isset($chosen_method_id) && $chosen_method_id === $shipping_method_id ) {
        return; // exit
    }

    // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
    if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __("The minimum required order amount is %s (your current order amount is %s).", "woocommerce"), // Text message
            wc_price( $minimum_amount ),
            wc_price( $cart_total )
        ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

or also you can use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_required_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_required_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_required_order_amount() {

    // HERE Your settings
    $minimum_amount     = 100; // The minimum cart total amount
    $shipping_method_id = 'local_pickup'; // The targeted shipping method Id (exception)

    // Get some variables
    $cart_total     = (float) WC()->cart->total; // Total cart amount
    $chosen_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // Chosen shipping method rate Ids (array)

    // Only when a shipping method has been chosen
    if ( ! empty($chosen_methods) ) {
        $chosen_method  = explode(':', reset($chosen_methods)); // Get the chosen shipping method Id (array)
        $chosen_method_id = reset($chosen_method); // Get the chosen shipping method Id
    }

    // If "Local pickup" shipping method is chosen, exit (no minimun is required)
    if ( isset($chosen_method_id) && $chosen_method_id === $shipping_method_id ) {
        return; // exit
    }

    // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
    if ( $cart_total < $minimum_amount ) {
        $text_notice = sprintf(
            __("The minimum required order amount is %s (your current order amount is %s).", "woocommerce"), // Text message
            wc_price( $minimum_amount ),
            wc_price( $cart_total )
        );
        
        if ( is_cart() ) {
            wc_print_notice( $text_notice, 'error' );
        } else {
            wc_add_notice( $text_notice, 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.